# Can I legally use setState in a promise in componentDidMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looking to avoid this warning which I can't otherwise debug: Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.

I currently have a fairly nested set of promises due to the sequencing of a few data calls. It seems as though the source of the warning is the line where I set the state for itemData, e.g. (this.setState({...itemData...).

Is this not a valid way of setting the state? (I removed some data to make it easier to read, e.g. the setting variables to 1, 2, 3

```
componentDidMount() {
    if(this.state.category && this.state.item){
      let { category, item, user, filter, filterVar } = this.state;
      var metaPromise = this.props.firebase.getItemMeta(category, item)
      .then(itemData => {
        let itemCollections = 1
        let subscribers = 2
        let reviewCount = 3

        this.setState({...itemData, itemCollections, itemData, subscribers, reviewCount }) //itemCollections is in itemData... why?
        return itemData
      })
      .then(() => {
        if( !user ){
          return []
        }
        return this.props.firebase.getUserCollectionsForItem(user.uid, category, item)
      })
      .then(userCollections => {
         this.setState({ userCollections })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("Error getting item data", error);
        return null;
      });


      Promise.all([metaPromise]).then(values => {
        //Do stuff here

        }).catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
          return Promise.reject(new Error("Error building collections", error));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This issue is when this particular component is unmounted while the requests haven't resolved. Generally this is reproducible when the component is tied to a URL. Its best to not tie the state of a component to an api response, but rather use a data storage system (self defined or a package like `redux`) to manage how data is saved and how a component updates / renders that data. You could also [**just keep track of a mounted flag**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43769931/2733506) if you really need to, but I'd prefer the first option if you can do that.

Comment: First of all, never use `var`, and your answer, maybe, in React whenever you change the state of the component, you fire a react update event, that triggers update cycle. When you do an update in the middle of a **lifecycle method**  before the component is mounted, you increase the chances of memory leak, in your case, don't seem too dangerous, but always respect warnings :).